# How to verify a Spring feature/Bug fix is available in the Spring boot version which i am using?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-io

I am working on a spring batch program to process data from sql and write to an xml. I used staxEventItemWriter to do that. But due to this issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1377 i am not able to fix the namespace issue. When we look at comments on this Jira card it says its fixed in 2010. But its not available in the latest spring boot versions which i am using. i tried with the patch class described in the Jira card its working fine for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.sitemap</groupId>
    <artifactId>SqlToXml</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SqlToXml</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-oxm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i got my answer from @Mahmoud Ben Hassine. I was actually checking on how to verify a patch is available on the spring version i am using. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to verify a Spring feature/Bug fix is available in the Spring boot version which i am using?

You are using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE. This will bring Spring Batch version 4.0.1.RELEASE. You can find more details about dependencies using the Spring Boot Initializr [REST API](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide).

The issue [BATCH-1377](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1377) is marked as resolved in version 2.1.0.RC1 and is also available in 4.0.1.RELEASE.

> But its not available in the latest spring boot versions which i am using. i tried with the patch class described in the Jira card its working fine for me.

The patch suggested by the contributor uses an additional property `rootTagNamePrefix` but this was modified as per [this comment](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1377?focusedCommentId=49911&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-49911) to use the naming convention `{uri}prefix:root` in order to be consistent with Spring WS. The issue was fixed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/commit/f56ee747296961917caa38fa9e14785dafc0b18b

So in your case, you need to use this naming convention if you want to add a namespace to the root tag. See example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/f56ee747296961917caa38fa9e14785dafc0b18b/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxEventItemWriterTests.java#L287